# cmake errors when building cppblog

Tags: cmake, cppcms

I installed cppcms in `~/progs/cppcms/cppcms-1.0.1/build`.
I installed all prerequisites for cppblog and trying to install the blog but I get errors:

```
~/progs/cppcms/cppblog_0.1.0/build 
> cmake ..
CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project, but they are set to NOTFOUND.
Please set them or make sure they are set and tested correctly in the CMake files:
INC_CPPDB
   used as include directory in directory /home/kirill/progs/cppcms/cppblog_0.1.0
INC_MARKDOWN
   used as include directory in directory /home/kirill/progs/cppcms/cppblog_0.1.0
LIB_CPPDB
    linked by target "cppblog" in directory /home/kirill/progs/cppcms/cppblog_0.1.0
    linked by target "cppblog_migrate" in directory /home/kirill/progs/cppcms/cppblog_0.1.0
LIB_MARKDOWN
    linked by target "cppblog" in directory /home/kirill/progs/cppcms/cppblog_0.1.0

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

I tried few things but couldn't get it to work. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

It hasn't been able to find the libs or include files for CppDB and Markdown.

Assuming these have been installed, you should be able to run CMake with the following parameters:

```
-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH:PATH=<path to CppDB lib>;<path to Markdown lib> -DCMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH:PATH=<path to CppDB includes>;<path to Markdown includes>
```

Answer (score 0):

The best place to ask such questions is within the cppcms mailing list: 
https://lists.sourceforge.net/lists/listinfo/cppcms-users

The cppcms creator is very actively supporting users there and you are sure to get the most appropriate answer.